# Multicell using FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I am creating a table with seven (7) columns:

PEDIDO | CANTIDAD | PENDIENTE | UNIDAD | DESCRIPCION | COSTO | NETO

And this is the loop I am using to populate the table:

```
do { 


    $pdf->Cell(20, 8,$row_Recordset11['ordered'], 0,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(20, 8,$row_Recordset11['quantity'], 0,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(20, 8,$row_Recordset11['pending'], 0,0,'C');

if ($row_Recordset11['material_or_service'] == 1){
    $pdf->Cell(20, 8, $row_Recordset11['unit_name'], 0,0,"C");


$cell_width = 70;
$current_y = $pdf->GetY();
$current_x = $pdf->GetX();

$pdf->MultiCell($cell_width, 8, $row_Recordset11['material_name'],0,"L", 0);

$pdf->SetXY($current_x + $cell_width, $current_y);
$current_x = $pdf->GetX();

}
if ($row_Recordset11['material_or_service'] == 2){
    $pdf->Cell(20, 8, $row_Recordset11['unit_name'], 0,0,"C");


$cell_width = 70;
$current_y = $pdf->GetY();
$current_x = $pdf->GetX();

$pdf->MultiCell($cell_width, 8, $row_Recordset11['service_name'],0,"L", 0);

$pdf->SetXY($current_x + $cell_width, $current_y);
$current_x = $pdf->GetX();

}
    $pdf->Cell(20, 8, "$ ".number_format($row_Recordset11['cost'], 2) , 0,0,'R');
    $pdf->Cell(20, 8, "$ ".number_format($row_Recordset11['net'], 2) , 0,0,'R');



    $pdf->Ln(4);
    } while ($row_Recordset11 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset11));
```

As you may see, the only column populated by MultiCell() objects is the column DESCRIPCION.

I am not getting the result I need. In this case, the first and second rows objects have two lines at column DESCRIPCION, but as you can see in the attached image, the two lines are printed out, but the second and third objects doesn't start just below where I expected...

[image]

Any help is welcome...

Comment: have you tried increasing the row height to see if it is too small for your font, ie. `$pdf->MultiCell($cell_width, 12, ...` instead of `$pdf->MultiCell($cell_width, 8, ...`?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it as follows:

```
do { 

$current_y = $pdf->GetY();
$current_x = $pdf->GetX();
$current_y2 = $current_y;
$current_x2 = $current_x;
    $pdf->Cell(20, 8,$row_Recordset11['ordered'], 0,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(20, 8,$row_Recordset11['quantity'], 0,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(20, 8,$row_Recordset11['pending'], 0,0,'C');

if ($row_Recordset11['material_or_service'] == 1){
    $pdf->Cell(20, 8, $row_Recordset11['unit_name'], 0,0,"C");


$cell_width = 70;
$current_x2 = $pdf->GetX();

$pdf->MultiCell($cell_width, 8, $row_Recordset11['material_name'],0,"L", 0);

$current_y2 = $pdf->GetY();


}


if ($row_Recordset11['material_or_service'] == 2){
    $pdf->Cell(20, 8, $row_Recordset11['unit_name'], 0,0,"C");


$cell_width = 70;
$current_x2 = $pdf->GetX();

$pdf->MultiCell($cell_width, 8, $row_Recordset11['service_name'],0,"L", 0);

$current_y2 = $pdf->GetY();


}



$pdf->SetXY($current_x2 + $cell_width, $current_y);


    $pdf->Cell(20, 8, "$ ".number_format($row_Recordset11['cost'], 2) , 0,0,'R');
    $pdf->Cell(20, 8, "$ ".number_format($row_Recordset11['net'], 2) , 0,0,'R');

$pdf->SetXY($current_x, $current_y2);


    } while ($row_Recordset11 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset11));
```